# Concat multiple columns as date and sort the data based on it using Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to sort the table data based on the date (by combining 3 fields) and limit the records.

we can do it by writing raw query like below:

```
SELECT * FROM employee 
order by STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(emp_date_day, '/', emp_date_month, '/', emp_date_year), '%d/%m/%Y') desc
limit 2;
```

But I would like to implement the same using JPA.
How can I do it in Spring Data JPA ?

Comment: Can you add a date field to the actual database table as well? That would make it easier to do what you want.

Comment: @locus2k No, I can't add date field. I should concat all 3 fields above and need to sort the data. that's the client requirement.

Comment: `CONCAT` exists in JPQL. Post what you have tried